# Magento 2: Authorize.Net: Transaction has been declined. Please try again later

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, payment-methods, authorize.net

I'm on `Magento 2.3.2`, Using `Authorize.Net [sandbox]` as my payment method, I'm unable to place order because I'm getting an error `Transaction has been declined. Please try again later.`, I see my `payment.log` i got this.

```
[2019-10-03 15:32:01] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'payload_type' => 'createTransactionRequest',
    'merchantAuthentication' => 
    array (
      'name' => '8RxFRSXd70A',
      'transactionKey' => '4469UffsC425Oc5A',
    ),
    'transactionRequest' => 
    array (
      'transactionType' => 'authOnlyTransaction',
      'amount' => '34.00',
      'payment' => 
      array (
        'opaqueData' => 
        array (
          'dataDescriptor' => NULL,
          'dataValue' => NULL,
        ),
      ),
      'solution' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'HHH102003',
      ),
      'order' => 
      array (
        'invoiceNumber' => '000002288',
      ),
      'poNumber' => NULL,
      'customer' => 
      array (
        'id' => '532',
        'email' => 'qamar@noname.com',
      ),
      'billTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'NoName',
        'lastName' => 'Test',
        'company' => 'NoName',
        'address' => '62 Chelsea Piers   ',
        'city' => 'New York',
        'state' => 'NY',
        'zip' => '10011',
        'country' => 'US',
      ),
      'shipTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'NoName',
        'lastName' => 'Test',
        'company' => 'NoName',
        'address' => '62 Chelsea Piers   ',
        'city' => 'New York',
        'state' => 'NY',
        'zip' => '10011',
        'country' => 'US',
      ),
      'customerIP' => '127.43.456.21',
      'userFields' => 
      array (
        'userField' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'transactionType',
            'value' => 'authOnlyTransaction',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'response' => '{"transactionResponse":{"SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0},"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00076","text":"dataDescriptor contains invalid value."},{"code":"E00076","text":"dataValue contains invalid value."}]}}',
) [] []
```

**Getting NULL value**

```
      'payment' => 
      array (
        'opaqueData' => 
        array (
          'dataDescriptor' => NULL,
          'dataValue' => NULL,
        ),
      ),
```

**Response**

```
'response' => 
    '{"transactionResponse":{"SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0},
    "messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[
    {"code":"E00076","text":"dataDescriptor contains invalid value."},
    {"code":"E00076","text":"dataValue contains invalid value."}]}}',
```

**Also i'm getting these in my Network**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had face similar issue like this, I tried to solve mine this way, you can try ,Please Follow these step.

> Step 1: Go to admin panel Store > Configuration > Sales > Payment
>   Method. Step 2:  Select Store View as Main Website.

[image]

> Step 3: Check all the boxes if they are not as `Use Default`

[image]

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this solved my issue.